# Correct way to load libraries (css/javascript) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, so please excuse me for asking a likely-basic question. I know the /assets is for files that are automatically loaded on a page request. But doesn't this mean that the server will always send all the files in this folder? Something doesn't seem right to me here.

This issue came up because I have been loading my css files from the /public folder, but realized that when I run my app in Firefox, none of the classes are recognized.

Anyway, I know that convention over configuration is a big thing in rails, so what is the convention for specifying what css/javascript files I want to be loaded on a per-page basis?

Comment: Question is kind of vague. What libraries? What classes? What lives in `public` and what lives in `assets`? I tried my best, but not sure it's "correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are probably in the [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), but I'll provide some info here too.

The server will only send these files all the time when your server is running in the development environment. In production, these files should be precompiled (using `rake assets:precompile`) so that as minimal amount of files are served as possible.

I'd encourage you to give the guide a more thorough read through for what I mean.

Comment: Great, this is the resource I needed.